# How to pass Authorization header in API POST call in dart?

Tags: api, flutter, authentication, dart, post

I'm working with flutter application and I want to know how we pass an authorization header in POST request. Here is the code I tried. I need help to know how to do this in the correct way.

```
    Future<String> addCartItemToDb({String userId}) async {
    try {
      final res = await http.post(
        _baseURL,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "accept": "*/*",
          "Authorization": "token"
        },
        body: jsonEncode({"userId": userID})
      );
      return _response(res);
    }on SocketException {
      throw CustomException("No internet Connection");
    }on FormatException {
      throw CustomException("Bad Response format !");
    }
  }
```

Further, I want to know how we decode that `token` I passed in the header to get `userid` to that user who already logged in.

Comment: Is this not helping you ? https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass headers in the HTTP post request in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58377795/how-to-pass-headers-in-the-http-post-request-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

```
final uri = Strings.base_url_api+Strings.nearby_cons;

var requestBody = {
  "organization_id": _orgID.toString()
};

http.Response response = await http.post(uri,
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $_auth'
  },
  body: requestBody,
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {

  var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print(responseJson);

} else {
  print('Status code error.. Check your API method or URL.. ');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

final jobsListAPIUrl = constants.BASE_URL+'bookings/retail/0/20/?status='+constants.BOOKING_CONFIRM_KEY+'&filter=0';
print(jobsListAPIUrl);
var response = await http.get(jobsListAPIUrl,headers: {'Authorization':'Token '+widget.token});
print(response.body);