# Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["Authorization "] in postman

Tags: json, windows, flutter, postman

I had trouble connecting to the pexel site API by the postman and it gives me the same error:

> Error: Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["Authorization "]

I do not know what to do.

Comment: please add postman screenshots

Comment: Maybe it's just your copying and pasting of the error message but that extra space at the end of the header name would probably show that error.

Answer (score 11):

There should be an empty line break between the header (content-type: application/json) and the request payload/data.

```
PATCH http://localhost:5000/users/61b6356454f499270755aee9
content-type: application/json

{
  "first_name": "John"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must put an empty line before your body

#### Invalid

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/report/expense/create HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "source": "Business",
    "amount": 200
}
```

#### Valid

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/report/expense/create HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "source": "Business",
    "amount": 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put your Authorization key in header parameters

{ "Authorization: YOUR_API_KEY" }

find more from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424761/how-to-pass-authorization-header-in-api-post-call-in-dart)

Comment: Hello my friend
I did but the problem was not solved

Answer (score 0):

**You can use http.Client() instead, like this:**

```
class API_Manager {
      Future<Model> getData() async {
        var client = http.Client();
        var Model;
        String url =
            'https://examplelink.com';
        String basicAuth = 'Basic your_auth_key_here';
        try {
          var response = await client.get(url,
              headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
          print(response.statusCode);
          developer.log(response.body); //to get your json data
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var jsonString = response.body;
            var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
            Model = MyModel.fromJson(jsonMap);
          }
        } catch (Exception) {
          return Model;
        }
        return Model;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, we have to write this part manually in the headers :)