# Dart parse nested map json

Tags: json, dictionary, dart, parsing, nested

I would like to map each of the attributes e.g. cashAndShortTermInvestments, accountsReceivable from below site in a Model class when parsing the json. Below are my codes and it doesn't seem to work. Appreciate if someone could help point where my codes are wrong and how it should be corrected.

Site: https://dev.last10k.com/docs/services/53c7e3aafd2dff034f040002/operations/5e2a9d30c8fa8071c307f0e2?

Thank you very much in advance!

```
class Financial {
  String name;
  Map<String, double> historical;
  Map<String, double>? recent;
  Map<String, String> category;

  Financial({
    required this.name,
    required this.historical,
    this.recent,
    required this.category,
  });

  factory Financial.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Financial(
      name: json['Name'],
      historical: Map.from(json['Historical']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String, double>(k, v.fromJson(v))),
      recent: json["Recent"] != null ? Map.from(json['Recent']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String, double>(k, v.fromJson(v))) : <String, double>{},
      category: Map.from(json['Category']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String, String>(k, v.fromJson(v))),
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Financial: {name = $name, '
        'historical: $historical, '
        'recent: $recent, '
        'category: $category }';
  }
} // class Financials

class RatiosModel {
  final Financial cashAndShortTermInvestments;
  final Financial accountsReceivable;
  final Financial inventory;
  final Financial otherCurrentAssets;
  final Financial totalCurrentAssets;
  final Financial netPPE;
  final Financial intangibles;
  final Financial otherLongTermAssets;
  final Financial totalAssets;
  final Financial accountsPayable;
  final Financial shortTermDebt;
  final Financial taxesPayable;
  final Financial accruedLiabilities;
  final Financial otherShortTermLiabilities;
  final Financial totalCurrentLiabilities;
  final Financial longTermDebt;
  final Financial otherLongTermLiabilities;
  final Financial totalLiabilities;
  final Financial totalStockholdersEquity;
  final Financial totalLiabilitiesEquity; // data probably no use
  final Financial currentRatio;
  final Financial quickRatio;
  final Financial financialLeverage;
  final Financial debtEquity;
  final Financial daysSalesOutstanding;
  final Financial daysInventory;
  final Financial payablesPeriod;
  final Financial cashConversionCycle;
  final Financial receivablesTurnover;
  final Financial inventoryTurnover;
  final Financial fixedAssetsTurnover;
  final Financial assetTurnover;
  final Financial bookValuePerShare;
  final Financial capSpending;
  final Financial dividends;
  final Financial earningsPerShare;
  final Financial freeCashFlowPerShare;
  final Financial freeCashFlow;
  final Financial grossMargin;
  final Financial netIncome;
  final Financial operatingCashFlow;
  final Financial operatingIncome;
  final Financial operatingMargin;
  final Financial payoutRatio;
  final Financial revenue;
  final Financial shares;
  final Financial workingCapital;
  final Financial cogs;
  final Financial grossSalesMargin;
  final Financial ebtMargin;
  final Financial netIntIncOther;
  final Financial otherSalesMargins;
  final Financial operationSalesMargin;
  final Financial researchAndDevelopment;
  final Financial sga;
  final Financial salesRevenue;
  final Financial assetTurnoverAverage;
  final Financial financialLeverageAverage;
  final Financial interestCoverage;
  final Financial netMargin;
  final Financial returnOnAssets;
  final Financial returnOnInvestedCapital;
  final Financial taxRate;
  final Financial revenueFiveYearAverage;
  final Financial revenueThreeYearAverage;
  final Financial revenueTenYearAverage;
  final Financial revenueYearOverYear;
  final Financial operatingIncomeFiveYearAverage;
  final Financial operatingIncomeTenYearAverage;
  final Financial operatingIncomeThreeYearAverage;
  final Financial operatingIncomeYearOverYear;
  final Financial netIncomeFiveYearAverage;
  final Financial netIncomeTenYearAverage;
  final Financial netIncomeThreeYearAverage;
  final Financial netIncomeYearOverYear;
  final Financial epsFiveYearAverage;
  final Financial epsTenYearAverage;
  final Financial epsThreeYearAverage;
  final Financial epsYearOverYear;
  final Financial operatingCashFlowYearOverYear;
  final Financial freeCashFlowYearOverYear;
  final Financial capExSales;
  final Financial freeCashFlowSales;
  final Financial freeCashFlowNetIncome;

  RatiosModel ({
    required this.cashAndShortTermInvestments,
    required this.accountsReceivable,
    required this.inventory,
    required this.otherCurrentAssets,
    required this.totalCurrentAssets,
    required this.netPPE,
    required this.intangibles,
    required this.otherLongTermAssets,
    required this.totalAssets,
    required this.accountsPayable,
    required this.shortTermDebt,
    required this.taxesPayable,
    required this.accruedLiabilities,
    required this.otherShortTermLiabilities,
    required this.totalCurrentLiabilities,
    required this.longTermDebt,
    required this.otherLongTermLiabilities,
    required this.totalLiabilities,
    required this.totalStockholdersEquity,
    required this.totalLiabilitiesEquity, // data probably no use
    required this.currentRatio,
    required this.quickRatio,
    required this.financialLeverage,
    required this.debtEquity,
    required this.daysSalesOutstanding,
    required this.daysInventory,
    required this.payablesPeriod,
    required this.cashConversionCycle,
    required this.receivablesTurnover,
    required this.inventoryTurnover,
    required this.fixedAssetsTurnover,
    required this.assetTurnover,
    required this.bookValuePerShare,
    required this.capSpending,
    required this.dividends,
    required this.earningsPerShare,
    required this.freeCashFlowPerShare,
    required this.freeCashFlow,
    required this.grossMargin,
    required this.netIncome,
    required this.operatingCashFlow,
    required this.operatingIncome,
    required this.operatingMargin,
    required this.payoutRatio,
    required this.revenue,
    required this.shares,
    required this.workingCapital,
    required this.cogs,
    required this.grossSalesMargin,
    required this.ebtMargin,
    required this.netIntIncOther,
    required this.otherSalesMargins,
    required this.operationSalesMargin,
    required this.researchAndDevelopment,
    required this.sga,
    required this.salesRevenue,
    required this.assetTurnoverAverage,
    required this.financialLeverageAverage,
    required this.interestCoverage,
    required this.netMargin,
    required this.returnOnAssets,
    required this.returnOnInvestedCapital,
    required this.taxRate,
    required this.revenueFiveYearAverage,
    required this.revenueThreeYearAverage,
    required this.revenueTenYearAverage,
    required this.revenueYearOverYear,
    required this.operatingIncomeFiveYearAverage,
    required this.operatingIncomeTenYearAverage,
    required this.operatingIncomeThreeYearAverage,
    required this.operatingIncomeYearOverYear,
    required this.netIncomeFiveYearAverage,
    required this.netIncomeTenYearAverage,
    required this.netIncomeThreeYearAverage,
    required this.netIncomeYearOverYear,
    required this.epsFiveYearAverage,
    required this.epsTenYearAverage,
    required this.epsThreeYearAverage,
    required this.epsYearOverYear,
    required this.operatingCashFlowYearOverYear,
    required this.freeCashFlowYearOverYear,
    required this.capExSales,
    required this.freeCashFlowSales,
    required this.freeCashFlowNetIncome
  });

  factory RatiosModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return RatiosModel(
      cashAndShortTermInvestments: json["CashAndShortTermInvestments"],
      accountsReceivable: json["AccountsReceivable"],
      inventory: json["Inventory"],
      otherCurrentAssets: json["OtherCurrentAssets"],
      totalCurrentAssets: json["TotalCurrentAssets"],
      netPPE: json["netPPE"],
      intangibles: json["Intangibles"],
      otherLongTermAssets: json["OtherLongTermAssets"],
      totalAssets: json["TotalAssets"],
      accountsPayable: json["AccountsPayable"],
      shortTermDebt: json["ShortTermDebt"],
      taxesPayable: json["TaxesPayable"],
      accruedLiabilities: json["AccruedLiabilities"],
      otherShortTermLiabilities: json["OtherShortTermLiabilities"],
      totalCurrentLiabilities: json["TotalCurrentLiabilities"],
      longTermDebt: json["LongTermDebt"],
      otherLongTermLiabilities: json["OtherLongTermLiabilities"],
      totalLiabilities: json["TotalLiabilities"],
      totalStockholdersEquity: json["TotalStockholdersEquity"],
      totalLiabilitiesEquity: json["TotalLiabilitiesEquity"], // data probably no use
      currentRatio: json["CurrentRatio"],
      quickRatio: json["QuickRatio"],
      financialLeverage: json["FinancialLeverage"],
      debtEquity: json["DebtEquity"],
      daysSalesOutstanding: json["DaysSalesOutstanding"],
      daysInventory: json["DaysInventory"],
      payablesPeriod: json["PayablesPeriod"],
      cashConversionCycle: json["CashConversionCycle"],
      receivablesTurnover: json["ReceivablesTurnover"],
      inventoryTurnover: json["InventoryTurnover"],
      fixedAssetsTurnover: json["FixedAssetsTurnover"],
      assetTurnover: json["AssetTurnover"],
      bookValuePerShare: json["BookValuePerShare"],
      capSpending: json["CapSpending"],
      dividends: json["Dividends"],
      earningsPerShare: json["EarningsPerShare"],
      freeCashFlowPerShare: json["FreeCashFlowPerShare"],
      freeCashFlow: json["FreeCashFlow"],
      grossMargin: json["GrossMargin"],
      netIncome: json["NetIncome"],
      operatingCashFlow: json["OperatingCashFlow"],
      operatingIncome: json["OperatingIncome"],
      operatingMargin: json["OperatingMargin"],
      payoutRatio: json["PayoutRatio"],
      revenue: json["Revenue"],
      shares: json["Shares"],
      workingCapital: json["WorkingCapital"],
      cogs: json["COGS"],
      grossSalesMargin: json["GrossSalesMargin"],
      ebtMargin: json["EBTMargin"],
      netIntIncOther: json["NetIntIncOther"],
      otherSalesMargins: json["OtherSalesMargins"],
      operationSalesMargin: json["OperationSalesMargin"],
      researchAndDevelopment: json["ResearchAndDevelopment"],
      sga: json["SGA"],
      salesRevenue: json["SalesRevenue"],
      assetTurnoverAverage: json["AssetTurnoverAverage"],
      financialLeverageAverage: json["FinancialLeverageAverage"],
      interestCoverage: json["InterestCoverage"],
      netMargin: json["NetMargin"],
      returnOnAssets: json["ReturnOnAssets"],
      returnOnInvestedCapital: json["ReturnOnInvestedCapital"],
      taxRate: json["TaxRate"],
      revenueFiveYearAverage: json["RevenueFiveYearAverage"],
      revenueThreeYearAverage: json["RevenueThreeYearAverage"],
      revenueTenYearAverage: json["RevenueTenYearAverage"],
      revenueYearOverYear: json["RevenueYearOverYear"],
      operatingIncomeFiveYearAverage: json["OperatingIncomeFiveYearAverage"],
      operatingIncomeTenYearAverage: json["OperatingIncomeTenYearAverage"],
      operatingIncomeThreeYearAverage: json["OperatingIncomeThreeYearAverage"],
      operatingIncomeYearOverYear: json["OperatingIncomeYearOverYear"],
      netIncomeFiveYearAverage: json["NetIncomeFiveYearAverage"],
      netIncomeTenYearAverage: json["NetIncomeTenYearAverage"],
      netIncomeThreeYearAverage: json["NetIncomeThreeYearAverage"],
      netIncomeYearOverYear: json["NetIncomeYearOverYear"],
      epsFiveYearAverage: json["EPSFiveYearAverage"],
      epsTenYearAverage: json["EPSTenYearAverage"],
      epsThreeYearAverage: json["EPSThreeYearAverage"],
      epsYearOverYear: json["EPSYearOverYear"],
      operatingCashFlowYearOverYear: json["OperatingCashFlowYearOverYear"],
      freeCashFlowYearOverYear: json["FreeCashFlowYearOverYear"],
      capExSales: json["CapExSales"],
      freeCashFlowSales: json["FreeCashFlowSales"],
      freeCashFlowNetIncome: json["FreeCashFlowNetIncome"],
    );
  } // factory TimeSeriesMetaData.fromJson

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'RatiosModel: {cashAndShortTermInvestments = $cashAndShortTermInvestments, '
        'accountsReceivable = $accountsReceivable, inventory = $inventory, '
        'otherCurrentAssets = $otherCurrentAssets, totalCurrentAssets = $totalCurrentAssets, '
        'netPPE= $netPPE, intangibles = $intangibles, otherLongTermAssets = $otherLongTermAssets, '
        'totalAssets = $totalAssets, accountsPayable = $accountsPayable, '
        'shortTermDebt = $shortTermDebt, taxesPayable = $taxesPayable, '
        'accruedLiabilities = $accruedLiabilities, otherShortTermLiabilities = $otherShortTermLiabilities, '
        'totalCurrentLiabilities = $totalCurrentLiabilities, longTermDebt = $longTermDebt, '
        'otherLongTermLiabilities = $otherLongTermLiabilities, totalLiabilities = $totalLiabilities, '
        'totalStockholdersEquity = $totalStockholdersEquity, totalLiabilitiesEquity = $totalLiabilitiesEquity, '
        'currentRatio = $currentRatio, quickRatio = $quickRatio, '
        'financialLeverage = $financialLeverage, debtEquity = $debtEquity, '
        'daysSalesOutstanding = $daysSalesOutstanding, daysInventory = $daysInventory, '
        'payablesPeriod = $payablesPeriod, cashConversionCycle = $cashConversionCycle, '
        'receivablesTurnover = $receivablesTurnover, inventoryTurnover = $inventoryTurnover, '
        'fixedAssetsTurnover = $fixedAssetsTurnover, assetTurnover = $assetTurnover, '
        'bookValuePerShare = $bookValuePerShare, capSpending = $capSpending, dividends = $dividends, '
        'earningsPerShare = $earningsPerShare, freeCashFlowPerShare = $freeCashFlowPerShare, '
        'freeCashFlow = $freeCashFlow, grossMargin = $grossMargin, netIncome = $netIncome, '
        'operatingIncome = $operatingIncome, operatingMargin = $operatingMargin, payoutRatio = $payoutRatio, '
        'payoutRatio = $payoutRatio, revenue = $revenue, shares = $shares, '
        'workingCapital = $workingCapital, cogs = $cogs, grossSalesMargin = $grossSalesMargin, '
        'ebtMargin = $ebtMargin, netIntIncOther = $netIntIncOther, otherSalesMargins = $otherSalesMargins, '
        'operationSalesMargin = $operationSalesMargin, researchAndDevelopment = $researchAndDevelopment, '
        'sga = $sga, salesRevenue = $salesRevenue, assetTurnoverAverage = $assetTurnoverAverage, '
        'financialLeverageAverage = $financialLeverageAverage, interestCoverage = $interestCoverage, '
        'netMargin = $netMargin, returnOnAssets = $returnOnAssets, '
        'returnOnInvestedCapital = $returnOnInvestedCapital, taxRate = $taxRate, '
        'revenueFiveYearAverage = $revenueFiveYearAverage, revenueThreeYearAverage = $revenueThreeYearAverage, '
        'revenueTenYearAverage = $revenueTenYearAverage, revenueYearOverYear = $revenueYearOverYear, '
        'operatingIncomeFiveYearAverage = $operatingIncomeFiveYearAverage, '
        'operatingIncomeTenYearAverage = $operatingIncomeTenYearAverage, '
        'operatingIncomeThreeYearAverage = $operatingIncomeThreeYearAverage, '
        'operatingIncomeYearOverYear = $operatingIncomeYearOverYear, '
        'netIncomeFiveYearAverage = $netIncomeFiveYearAverage, netIncomeTenYearAverage = $netIncomeTenYearAverage, '
        'netIncomeThreeYearAverage = $netIncomeThreeYearAverage, netIncomeYearOverYear = $netIncomeYearOverYear, '
        'epsFiveYearAverage = $epsFiveYearAverage, epsTenYearAverage = $epsTenYearAverage, '
        'epsThreeYearAverage = $epsThreeYearAverage, epsYearOverYear = $epsYearOverYear, '
        'operatingCashFlowYearOverYear = $operatingCashFlowYearOverYear, '
        'freeCashFlowYearOverYear = $freeCashFlowYearOverYear, capExSales = $capExSales, '
        'freeCashFlowSales = $freeCashFlowSales, freeCashFlowNetIncome }';
  } // toString
} // class RatiosModel


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

void main() async { 
  runApp(MyApp());
} // main

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Global Fleas',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: Test(),
    );
  } // Widget build(BuildContext context)
}
 
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test({Key? key/*, this.title*/}) : super(key: key);
  //final String title;
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  late Future <RatiosModel> _ratios;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _ratios = _getRatios();
    //_getRatios();
  } // void initState()

  Future <RatiosModel> _getRatios() async {
    String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/last10k_ratios.json');
    dynamic jsonObject = json.decode(response);
    final convertedJsonObject = jsonObject.cast<dynamic, dynamic>();
    print('convertedJsonObject: ${convertedJsonObject["data"]["attributes"]["result"]}');
    RatiosModel ratios =
        convertedJsonObject["data"]["attributes"]["result"].map<RatiosModel>((json) =>
            RatiosModel.fromJson(json));
    print('ratios: $ratios');
    return ratios;
  } // Future <RatiosModel> _getRatios() async

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder( // Day Performance - Dow Jones
          future: _ratios,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<RatiosModel> snapshot,)
          {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Text('Error');
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text('test');//_getBodyWidget(snapshot.data!);
              } else {
                return const Text('No data');
              }
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();//Text('State: ${snapshot.connectionState}');
            }
          }),
    );
  } // Widget build(BuildContext context)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue.. i should have done below for each attribute in factory RatiosModel constructor

```
cashAndShortTermInvestments: Financial.fromJson(json["CashAndShortTermInvestments"]),
```

also, i have changed the parameter of the factory constructor to (dynamic json)

i also corrected below in factory Financial.fromJson(dynamic json)

```
historical: Map.from(json['Historical']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String, double>(k, v)),

category: Map.from(json['Category']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String, String>(k, v)),


class Financial {
  String name;
  Map<String, double> historical;
  Map<String, double>? recent;
  Map<String, String> category;

  Financial({
    required this.name,
    required this.historical,
    this.recent,
    required this.category,
  });

  factory Financial.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return Financial(
      name: json['Name'],
      historical: Map.from(json['Historical']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String, double>(k, v)),
      recent: json["Recent"] != null ? Map.from(json['Recent']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String, double>(k, v)) : <String, double>{},
      category: Map.from(json['Category']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String, String>(k, v)),
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Financial: {name = $name, '
        'historical: $historical, '
        'recent: $recent, '
        'category: $category }';
  }
} // class Financials

class RatiosModel {
  final Financial cashAndShortTermInvestments;
  final Financial accountsReceivable;
  final Financial inventory;
  final Financial otherCurrentAssets;
  final Financial totalCurrentAssets;
  final Financial netPPE;
  final Financial intangibles;
  final Financial otherLongTermAssets;
  final Financial totalAssets;
  final Financial accountsPayable;
  final Financial shortTermDebt;
  final Financial taxesPayable;
  final Financial accruedLiabilities;
  final Financial otherShortTermLiabilities;
  final Financial totalCurrentLiabilities;
  final Financial longTermDebt;
  final Financial otherLongTermLiabilities;
  final Financial totalLiabilities;
  final Financial totalStockholdersEquity;
  final Financial totalLiabilitiesEquity; // data probably no use
  final Financial currentRatio;
  final Financial quickRatio;
  final Financial financialLeverage;
  final Financial debtEquity;
  final Financial daysSalesOutstanding;
  final Financial daysInventory;
  final Financial payablesPeriod;
  final Financial cashConversionCycle;
  final Financial receivablesTurnover;
  final Financial inventoryTurnover;
  final Financial fixedAssetsTurnover;
  final Financial assetTurnover;
  final Financial bookValuePerShare;
  final Financial capSpending;
  final Financial dividends;
  final Financial earningsPerShare;
  final Financial freeCashFlowPerShare;
  final Financial freeCashFlow;
  final Financial grossMargin;
  final Financial netIncome;
  final Financial operatingCashFlow;
  final Financial operatingIncome;
  final Financial operatingMargin;
  final Financial payoutRatio;
  final Financial revenue;
  final Financial shares;
  final Financial workingCapital;
  final Financial cogs;
  final Financial grossSalesMargin;
  final Financial ebtMargin;
  final Financial netIntIncOther;
  final Financial otherSalesMargins;
  final Financial operationSalesMargin;
  final Financial researchAndDevelopment;
  final Financial sga;
  final Financial salesRevenue;
  final Financial assetTurnoverAverage;
  final Financial financialLeverageAverage;
  final Financial interestCoverage;
  final Financial netMargin;
  final Financial returnOnAssets;
  final Financial returnOnInvestedCapital;
  final Financial taxRate;
  final Financial revenueFiveYearAverage;
  final Financial revenueThreeYearAverage;
  final Financial revenueTenYearAverage;
  final Financial revenueYearOverYear;
  final Financial operatingIncomeFiveYearAverage;
  final Financial operatingIncomeTenYearAverage;
  final Financial operatingIncomeThreeYearAverage;
  final Financial operatingIncomeYearOverYear;
  final Financial netIncomeFiveYearAverage;
  final Financial netIncomeTenYearAverage;
  final Financial netIncomeThreeYearAverage;
  final Financial netIncomeYearOverYear;
  final Financial epsFiveYearAverage;
  final Financial epsTenYearAverage;
  final Financial epsThreeYearAverage;
  final Financial epsYearOverYear;
  final Financial operatingCashFlowYearOverYear;
  final Financial freeCashFlowYearOverYear;
  final Financial capExSales;
  final Financial freeCashFlowSales;
  final Financial freeCashFlowNetIncome;

  RatiosModel ({
    required this.cashAndShortTermInvestments,
    required this.accountsReceivable,
    required this.inventory,
    required this.otherCurrentAssets,
    required this.totalCurrentAssets,
    required this.netPPE,
    required this.intangibles,
    required this.otherLongTermAssets,
    required this.totalAssets,
    required this.accountsPayable,
    required this.shortTermDebt,
    required this.taxesPayable,
    required this.accruedLiabilities,
    required this.otherShortTermLiabilities,
    required this.totalCurrentLiabilities,
    required this.longTermDebt,
    required this.otherLongTermLiabilities,
    required this.totalLiabilities,
    required this.totalStockholdersEquity,
    required this.totalLiabilitiesEquity, // data probably no use
    required this.currentRatio,
    required this.quickRatio,
    required this.financialLeverage,
    required this.debtEquity,
    required this.daysSalesOutstanding,
    required this.daysInventory,
    required this.payablesPeriod,
    required this.cashConversionCycle,
    required this.receivablesTurnover,
    required this.inventoryTurnover,
    required this.fixedAssetsTurnover,
    required this.assetTurnover,
    required this.bookValuePerShare,
    required this.capSpending,
    required this.dividends,
    required this.earningsPerShare,
    required this.freeCashFlowPerShare,
    required this.freeCashFlow,
    required this.grossMargin,
    required this.netIncome,
    required this.operatingCashFlow,
    required this.operatingIncome,
    required this.operatingMargin,
    required this.payoutRatio,
    required this.revenue,
    required this.shares,
    required this.workingCapital,
    required this.cogs,
    required this.grossSalesMargin,
    required this.ebtMargin,
    required this.netIntIncOther,
    required this.otherSalesMargins,
    required this.operationSalesMargin,
    required this.researchAndDevelopment,
    required this.sga,
    required this.salesRevenue,
    required this.assetTurnoverAverage,
    required this.financialLeverageAverage,
    required this.interestCoverage,
    required this.netMargin,
    required this.returnOnAssets,
    required this.returnOnInvestedCapital,
    required this.taxRate,
    required this.revenueFiveYearAverage,
    required this.revenueThreeYearAverage,
    required this.revenueTenYearAverage,
    required this.revenueYearOverYear,
    required this.operatingIncomeFiveYearAverage,
    required this.operatingIncomeTenYearAverage,
    required this.operatingIncomeThreeYearAverage,
    required this.operatingIncomeYearOverYear,
    required this.netIncomeFiveYearAverage,
    required this.netIncomeTenYearAverage,
    required this.netIncomeThreeYearAverage,
    required this.netIncomeYearOverYear,
    required this.epsFiveYearAverage,
    required this.epsTenYearAverage,
    required this.epsThreeYearAverage,
    required this.epsYearOverYear,
    required this.operatingCashFlowYearOverYear,
    required this.freeCashFlowYearOverYear,
    required this.capExSales,
    required this.freeCashFlowSales,
    required this.freeCashFlowNetIncome
  });

  factory RatiosModel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    Financial test = Financial.fromJson(json["CashAndShortTermInvestments"]);
    print('test: $test');
    return RatiosModel(
      cashAndShortTermInvestments: Financial.fromJson(json["CashAndShortTermInvestments"]),
      accountsReceivable: Financial.fromJson(json["AccountsReceivable"]),
      inventory: Financial.fromJson(json["Inventory"]),
      otherCurrentAssets: Financial.fromJson(json["OtherCurrentAssets"]),
      totalCurrentAssets: Financial.fromJson(json["TotalCurrentAssets"]),
      netPPE: Financial.fromJson(json["NetPPE"]),
      intangibles: Financial.fromJson(json["Intangibles"]),
      otherLongTermAssets: Financial.fromJson(json["OtherLongTermAssets"]),
      totalAssets: Financial.fromJson(json["TotalAssets"]),
      accountsPayable: Financial.fromJson(json["AccountsPayable"]),
      shortTermDebt: Financial.fromJson(json["ShortTermDebt"]),
      taxesPayable: Financial.fromJson(json["TaxesPayable"]),
      accruedLiabilities: Financial.fromJson(json["AccruedLiabilities"]),
      otherShortTermLiabilities: Financial.fromJson(json["OtherShortTermLiabilities"]),
      totalCurrentLiabilities: Financial.fromJson(json["TotalCurrentLiabilities"]),
      longTermDebt: Financial.fromJson(json["LongTermDebt"]),
      otherLongTermLiabilities: Financial.fromJson(json["OtherLongTermLiabilities"]),
      totalLiabilities: Financial.fromJson(json["TotalLiabilities"]),
      totalStockholdersEquity: Financial.fromJson(json["TotalStockholdersEquity"]),
      totalLiabilitiesEquity: Financial.fromJson(json["TotalLiabilitiesEquity"]), // data probably no use
      currentRatio: Financial.fromJson(json["CurrentRatio"]),
      quickRatio: Financial.fromJson(json["QuickRatio"]),
      financialLeverage: Financial.fromJson(json["FinancialLeverage"]),
      debtEquity: Financial.fromJson(json["DebtEquity"]),
      daysSalesOutstanding: Financial.fromJson(json["DaysSalesOutstanding"]),
      daysInventory: Financial.fromJson(json["DaysInventory"]),
      payablesPeriod: Financial.fromJson(json["PayablesPeriod"]),
      cashConversionCycle: Financial.fromJson(json["CashConversionCycle"]),
      receivablesTurnover: Financial.fromJson(json["ReceivablesTurnover"]),
      inventoryTurnover: Financial.fromJson(json["InventoryTurnover"]),
      fixedAssetsTurnover: Financial.fromJson(json["FixedAssetsTurnover"]),
      assetTurnover: Financial.fromJson(json["AssetTurnover"]),
      bookValuePerShare: Financial.fromJson(json["BookValuePerShare"]),
      capSpending: Financial.fromJson(json["CapSpending"]),
      dividends: Financial.fromJson(json["Dividends"]),
      earningsPerShare: Financial.fromJson(json["EarningsPerShare"]),
      freeCashFlowPerShare: Financial.fromJson(json["FreeCashFlowPerShare"]),
      freeCashFlow: Financial.fromJson(json["FreeCashFlow"]),
      grossMargin: Financial.fromJson(json["GrossMargin"]),
      netIncome: Financial.fromJson(json["NetIncome"]),
      operatingCashFlow: Financial.fromJson(json["OperatingCashFlow"]),
      operatingIncome: Financial.fromJson(json["OperatingIncome"]),
      operatingMargin: Financial.fromJson(json["OperatingMargin"]),
      payoutRatio: Financial.fromJson(json["PayoutRatio"]),
      revenue: Financial.fromJson(json["Revenue"]),
      shares: Financial.fromJson(json["Shares"]),
      workingCapital: Financial.fromJson(json["WorkingCapital"]),
      cogs: Financial.fromJson(json["COGS"]),
      grossSalesMargin: Financial.fromJson(json["GrossSalesMargin"]),
      ebtMargin: Financial.fromJson(json["EBTMargin"]),
      netIntIncOther: Financial.fromJson(json["NetIntIncOther"]),
      otherSalesMargins: Financial.fromJson(json["OtherSalesMargins"]),
      operationSalesMargin: Financial.fromJson(json["OperationSalesMargin"]),
      researchAndDevelopment: Financial.fromJson(json["ResearchAndDevelopment"]),
      sga: Financial.fromJson(json["SGA"]),
      salesRevenue: Financial.fromJson(json["SalesRevenue"]),
      assetTurnoverAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["AssetTurnoverAverage"]),
      financialLeverageAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["FinancialLeverageAverage"]),
      interestCoverage: Financial.fromJson(json["InterestCoverage"]),
      netMargin: Financial.fromJson(json["NetMargin"]),
      returnOnAssets: Financial.fromJson(json["ReturnOnAssets"]),
      returnOnInvestedCapital: Financial.fromJson(json["ReturnOnInvestedCapital"]),
      taxRate: Financial.fromJson(json["TaxRate"]),
      revenueFiveYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["RevenueFiveYearAverage"]),
      revenueThreeYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["RevenueThreeYearAverage"]),
      revenueTenYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["RevenueTenYearAverage"]),
      revenueYearOverYear: Financial.fromJson(json["RevenueYearOverYear"]),
      operatingIncomeFiveYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["OperatingIncomeFiveYearAverage"]),
      operatingIncomeTenYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["OperatingIncomeTenYearAverage"]),
      operatingIncomeThreeYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["OperatingIncomeThreeYearAverage"]),
      operatingIncomeYearOverYear: Financial.fromJson(json["OperatingIncomeYearOverYear"]),
      netIncomeFiveYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["NetIncomeFiveYearAverage"]),
      netIncomeTenYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["NetIncomeTenYearAverage"]),
      netIncomeThreeYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["NetIncomeThreeYearAverage"]),
      netIncomeYearOverYear: Financial.fromJson(json["NetIncomeYearOverYear"]),
      epsFiveYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["EPSFiveYearAverage"]),
      epsTenYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["EPSTenYearAverage"]),
      epsThreeYearAverage: Financial.fromJson(json["EPSThreeYearAverage"]),
      epsYearOverYear: Financial.fromJson(json["EPSYearOverYear"]),
      operatingCashFlowYearOverYear: Financial.fromJson(json["OperatingCashFlowYearOverYear"]),
      freeCashFlowYearOverYear: Financial.fromJson(json["FreeCashFlowYearOverYear"]),
      capExSales: Financial.fromJson(json["CapExSales"]),
      freeCashFlowSales: Financial.fromJson(json["FreeCashFlowSales"]),
      freeCashFlowNetIncome: Financial.fromJson(json["FreeCashFlowNetIncome"]),
    );
  } // factory TimeSeriesMetaData.fromJson

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'RatiosModel: {cashAndShortTermInvestments = $cashAndShortTermInvestments, '
        'accountsReceivable = $accountsReceivable, inventory = $inventory, '
        'otherCurrentAssets = $otherCurrentAssets, totalCurrentAssets = $totalCurrentAssets, '
        'netPPE= $netPPE, intangibles = $intangibles, otherLongTermAssets = $otherLongTermAssets, '
        'totalAssets = $totalAssets, accountsPayable = $accountsPayable, '
        'shortTermDebt = $shortTermDebt, taxesPayable = $taxesPayable, '
        'accruedLiabilities = $accruedLiabilities, otherShortTermLiabilities = $otherShortTermLiabilities, '
        'totalCurrentLiabilities = $totalCurrentLiabilities, longTermDebt = $longTermDebt, '
        'otherLongTermLiabilities = $otherLongTermLiabilities, totalLiabilities = $totalLiabilities, '
        'totalStockholdersEquity = $totalStockholdersEquity, totalLiabilitiesEquity = $totalLiabilitiesEquity, '
        'currentRatio = $currentRatio, quickRatio = $quickRatio, '
        'financialLeverage = $financialLeverage, debtEquity = $debtEquity, '
        'daysSalesOutstanding = $daysSalesOutstanding, daysInventory = $daysInventory, '
        'payablesPeriod = $payablesPeriod, cashConversionCycle = $cashConversionCycle, '
        'receivablesTurnover = $receivablesTurnover, inventoryTurnover = $inventoryTurnover, '
        'fixedAssetsTurnover = $fixedAssetsTurnover, assetTurnover = $assetTurnover, '
        'bookValuePerShare = $bookValuePerShare, capSpending = $capSpending, dividends = $dividends, '
        'earningsPerShare = $earningsPerShare, freeCashFlowPerShare = $freeCashFlowPerShare, '
        'freeCashFlow = $freeCashFlow, grossMargin = $grossMargin, netIncome = $netIncome, '
        'operatingIncome = $operatingIncome, operatingMargin = $operatingMargin, payoutRatio = $payoutRatio, '
        'payoutRatio = $payoutRatio, revenue = $revenue, shares = $shares, '
        'workingCapital = $workingCapital, cogs = $cogs, grossSalesMargin = $grossSalesMargin, '
        'ebtMargin = $ebtMargin, netIntIncOther = $netIntIncOther, otherSalesMargins = $otherSalesMargins, '
        'operationSalesMargin = $operationSalesMargin, researchAndDevelopment = $researchAndDevelopment, '
        'sga = $sga, salesRevenue = $salesRevenue, assetTurnoverAverage = $assetTurnoverAverage, '
        'financialLeverageAverage = $financialLeverageAverage, interestCoverage = $interestCoverage, '
        'netMargin = $netMargin, returnOnAssets = $returnOnAssets, '
        'returnOnInvestedCapital = $returnOnInvestedCapital, taxRate = $taxRate, '
        'revenueFiveYearAverage = $revenueFiveYearAverage, revenueThreeYearAverage = $revenueThreeYearAverage, '
        'revenueTenYearAverage = $revenueTenYearAverage, revenueYearOverYear = $revenueYearOverYear, '
        'operatingIncomeFiveYearAverage = $operatingIncomeFiveYearAverage, '
        'operatingIncomeTenYearAverage = $operatingIncomeTenYearAverage, '
        'operatingIncomeThreeYearAverage = $operatingIncomeThreeYearAverage, '
        'operatingIncomeYearOverYear = $operatingIncomeYearOverYear, '
        'netIncomeFiveYearAverage = $netIncomeFiveYearAverage, netIncomeTenYearAverage = $netIncomeTenYearAverage, '
        'netIncomeThreeYearAverage = $netIncomeThreeYearAverage, netIncomeYearOverYear = $netIncomeYearOverYear, '
        'epsFiveYearAverage = $epsFiveYearAverage, epsTenYearAverage = $epsTenYearAverage, '
        'epsThreeYearAverage = $epsThreeYearAverage, epsYearOverYear = $epsYearOverYear, '
        'operatingCashFlowYearOverYear = $operatingCashFlowYearOverYear, '
        'freeCashFlowYearOverYear = $freeCashFlowYearOverYear, capExSales = $capExSales, '
        'freeCashFlowSales = $freeCashFlowSales, freeCashFlowNetIncome }';
  } // toString
} // class RatiosModel


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

import 'package:globalfleas/models/ratios_model.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test({Key? key/*, this.title*/}) : super(key: key);
  //final String title;
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  //late Future <RatiosModel> _ratios;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //_ratios = _getRatios();
    _getRatios();
  } // void initState()

  //Future <RatiosModel> _getRatios() async {
  _getRatios() async {
    /*// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58377795/how-to-pass-headers-in-the-http-post-request-in-flutter
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://services.last10k.com/v1/company/ibm/ratios'),
      // Send authorization headers to the backend.
      headers: {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'a22e5957bd6a4f43ac1af306db39c00b'
      },
    );
    print('response: ${response.body}');
    dynamic jsonObject = json.decode(response.body);
    */
    String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/last10k_ratios.json');
    dynamic jsonObject = json.decode(response);
    final convertedJsonObject = jsonObject.cast<dynamic, dynamic>();
    print('convertedJsonObject: ${convertedJsonObject["data"]["attributes"]["result"]}');
    Financial financials = Financial.fromJson(convertedJsonObject["data"]["attributes"]["result"]['CashAndShortTermInvestments']);
    print('financials: $financials');
    RatiosModel ratios = RatiosModel.fromJson(convertedJsonObject["data"]["attributes"]["result"]);
      /*convertedJsonObject["data"]["attributes"]["result"].map<RatiosModel>((json) =>
        RatiosModel.fromJson(json)).toList();*/
    print('ratios: $ratios');
    print('ratios[cashAndShortTermInvestments]: ${ratios.cashAndShortTermInvestments}');
    //return ratios;
  } // Future <RatiosModel> _getRatios() async

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('test'),
    );
  } // Widget build(BuildContext context)

}
```